# Discordbot(Python) who should start bat file(Minecraft server) can't find user_jvm_args.txt file

Tags: python, batch-file, discord

I want to make a discord bot in pyhton to start a minecraft server so a bat file but it cant find the user_jvm_args.txt file even when i say the code where it is. I am not good a coding I did most parts with Chatgpt if there are weird lines
Yes I imported the token.
here is the code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands 
import subprocess
import os
import asyncio

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())
running_process = None
BOT_TOKEN = 'Token'  # Replace 'YOUR_DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN' with your actual Discord bot token

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("The bot is now ready for use!")

@client.command()
async def start(ctx):
    global running_process
    if running_process and running_process.poll() is None:
        await ctx.send("A process is already running.")
        return

    batch_file_path = r"C:/Users/tomwi/Desktop/Dommmamjaydenantom/run.bat"  # Update this path
    user_jvm_args_path = r"C:/Users/tomwi/Desktop/Dommmamjaydenantom/user_jvm_args.txt"  # Update this path
    try:
        await execute_batch_file(ctx, batch_file_path, user_jvm_args_path)
    except Exception as e:
        await ctx.send(f"Failed to start batch file: {e}")

async def execute_batch_file(ctx, batch_file_path, user_jvm_args_path):
    with open(user_jvm_args_path, 'r') as f:
        user_jvm_args = f.read().strip()
    command = f'java @{user_jvm_args} -Xmx10G -Xms9G "{batch_file_path}"'
    running_process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(command)
    await ctx.send("Batch file started.")

@client.command()
async def stop(ctx):
    global running_process
    if running_process and running_process.poll() is None:
        try:
            running_process.terminate()
            await ctx.send("Batch file stopped.")
        except Exception as e:
            await ctx.send(f"Failed to stop batch file: {e}")
    else:
        await ctx.send("No batch file is currently running.")

client.run(BOT_TOKEN)
```

I tried many things like putting the file in the directory of the bot origanlly the file wasn't metionend in the code but then I implementet it and it did nothing
but like I said I don't know anything when it comes to programing

Comment: Not only is a bat file for command.com, not cmd.exe, and completely unnecessary for starting a server, but you have not submitted that batch file content either! Also, it is not the purpose of this site to fix AI generated code, especially with no debugging information.